# Python - Celery autorelaod

Tags: python, celery

How does you develop when using celery ?
Seem it require reload for every change,

I'm using command:

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=proj/ -p '*.py' --recursive --  celery -A proj worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

cellery.py

```py
from decouple import AutoConfig

cwd = os.getcwd()
DOTENV_FILE = cwd + '/proj/config/.env'


config = AutoConfig(search_path='DOTENV_FILE')

app = Celery('proj',
             broker=config('CELERY_BROKER_URL'),
             backend=config('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'),
             include=['proj.tasks'])


app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py

```py
from .celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a technical solution for this kind of reloading I would suggest you shouldn't use celery stuff as you develop your task function because, well, it's just a function! So my approach here is to get the function done first and add celery stuff then to check if it integrates well with other things like tasks in the chain, django, etc. The same technic will apply if you think about unit testing.